# Cannot find module '/static/media/profile.png'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to use .png files in my React project. I am using typescript. Although I wrote:

- `declare module "*.png";` in `react-app-env.d.ts` file
- `import image from '../../images/profile.png'` and `<Image src={require(image)} alt="profile"/>`

I still reveice error:
`Cannot find module '/static/media/profile.61e9dd382cf050df64b8.png'`

Comment: What if you try `import image from 'path'` then use it `<Image src={image} />`?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, for everyone who has the same problem. Instead of importing images try:
`const image = require("../../images/profile.png")`

and the just:
`<Image src={image} alt="profile"/>`